# Ant concat fileset separator

Tags: ant

When using concat with fileset in Ant, how do I make an action happen for each element in the fileset. Such as, adding a string:

```
<fileset dir="${project.path.scripts-library}"
                excludes="!*.js, **/*.bak, **/dev.*"
>
    <type type="file" />
    <include name="**/0*.js" />
    <include name="**/1*.js" />
    <string>test</string>
</fileset>
```

Or echoing the current file name for each file in the fileset (and, how do I GET the file name for the current file???):

```
<fileset dir="${project.path.scripts-library}"
                excludes="!*.js, **/*.bak, **/dev.*"
>
    <echo file="${app.path.file}" 
            append="true"
            message=",${the.file.name}" />

    <type type="file" />
    <include name="**/0*.js" />
    <include name="**/1*.js" />
</fileset>
```

Comment: When you say 'concat test', do you mean add 'test' to the end of each filename, or to the end of each line in each file?

Comment: I mean, the files are being concatenated into a single text file. After each file is concatenated into that text file, also concatenate the contents of <string> (in this case test) into that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no such thing in default ant. The closest one is [`<apply>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html), but it's system specific:

```
<apply executable="echo"> <!-- run this command with each file name -->
  <fileset dir="/tmp" includes="**/*.*"/>
</apply>
```

Also you can install [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to enable [`<for>`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) task:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="/tmp" includes="**/*.*"/>
  </path>
  <sequential> <!-- run any task here -->
    <echo>file [@{file}]</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: For all those searching only for a way to append a new line after each file: fixlastline="yes".